# Is this expansion related to Pochhammer's symbol, the gamma function, and beta function valid for $a<0$ and $a\neq 0,-1,-2,\ldots$?

Tags: alternative-proof, gamma-function, beta-function, pochhammer-symbol

If I start with the [definition of the beta function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.12.E1)
$$B(a,b) = \int_0^1 t^{a-1} (1-t)^{b-1} \operatorname{d}t = \frac{\Gamma(a) \Gamma(b)}{\Gamma(a+b)}$$
that is valid for $\mathcal{R}(a) >0$ and $\mathcal{R}(b) > 0$, and apply a [binomial expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Generalizations) to the second factor in the argument of the integral, I ultimately get:
$$\frac{\Gamma(a)}{\Gamma(a+b)} = \frac{1}{(a)_b} = \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^j}{j!\, \Gamma(b-j)\, (a+j)},$$
with $(x)_n$ being [Pochhammer's symbol](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.2.iii).

The starting point of the derivation is only valid for the real part of $a>0$. The use case I have requires it to be valid for $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a\notin \{n \in \mathbb{Z}\ |\ n \le 0\}$ (i.e. $a-1$ is not a negative integer). I've looked numerically at various cases of $b$ with $50$ terms in the sum, and it appears to converge to the fraction using gamma functions.

For example, in this graph with $a$ as the $x$-axis I've used $b=2.7$ and plotted the sum as a blue dashed line, and the ratio of gamma functions as the solid red line. The graphs overlap similarly for $b$ as positive and negative integers and non-integers.
[image: Pochhammer identity comparison]

I'm asking this question because I'm surprised that it appears to be valid for more values than the derivation's starting point allows, and want to know if a more robust derivation is possible.

There's an identity in [Wikipedia's beta function article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Properties) that is identical
$$B(x,y) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{{n-y \choose n}}{x+n}$$
if you use gamma functions to expand the parts of the choose function that involve $y$ and apply the [reflection identity](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.5.E3) to both gamma functions. The only citation for the section is [Abramowitz and Stegun](https://archive.org/details/AandS-mono600), which does not contain the identity from Wikipedia.

The [MathWorld page on the incomplete beta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteBetaFunction.html) has a formula that reduces to the Wikipedia one when plugging in $z=1$ (equation 5)
$$B(z;a,b)= z^a \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(1-b)_n}{n!\, (a+n)} z^n,$$
and the only reference on that page, ["Tables of the Incomplete Beta Function" by Karl Pearson (2nd ed)](https://archive.org/details/tablesofincomple00pear), does not contain this formula.

Comment: The key may lie in judicious use of the [Pochhammer contour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pochhammer_contour) or similar. But it's not unusual for derivations using analytic functions to rely on analytic continuation: functional equations are often proved in an open subset, and extended by analytic continuation, for example.

Comment: But certainly if the sum works for any $a$, it will work on the set you specify, since the $1/(a+j)$ terms are eventually decreasing no matter what the value of $a$ is.